# simplify linked list pointer loop

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

was trying to scan numbers from a file and store them as linked list, however the temporary pointer (ptr) used to link nodes runs through a while loop each time a value is scanned and stored. Is there a way to simplify this without using a while loop? My approach doesn't seem to work.

original code:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *link;
} *head = NULL, *ptr = NULL, *temp = NULL;

int main()
{
-----
-----
for (i = 0; i < n ; ++i)
    {
        temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        fscanf(fptr, "%d", &(temp->data));
        temp->link = NULL;

        if (head == NULL)
            head = temp;
        
        else
        {
            ptr = head;
            while (ptr->link != NULL)
                ptr = ptr->link;
            ptr->link = temp;
        }
    }
-----
}
```

my approach:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *link;
} *head = NULL, *ptr = NULL, *temp = NULL;

int main()
{
-----
-----
for (i = 0; i < n ; ++i)
{
    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    fscanf(fptr, "%d", &(temp->data));
    temp->link = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = temp;
        ptr = head;
    }
    
    else
    {
        ptr->link = temp;
        ptr->link = ptr->link->link;
    }
}
-----
}
```

Comment: you can keep track of a separate `tail` pointer and insert new nodes there without looping through to find the end.

Comment: @yano: beat me by a few seconds. I don't know why most tutorials and books only mention a tail pointer in the context of a double linked list. It's a simple and valuable improvement to a single linked list.

Comment: Can you explain `ptr->link = ptr->link->link`

Answer (score 0):

In this code snippet

```
else
{
    ptr->link = temp;
    ptr->link = ptr->link->link;
}
```

`ptr->link` is set to `NULL` because in fact it is set to `temp->link` that is equal to `NULL` due to this assignment

```
temp->link = NULL;
```

What you need is to write

```
else
{
    ptr->link = temp;
    ptr = temp;
}
```

Actually you are trying to implement a two-sided sinngly-linked list where the pointer `ptr` plays the role of the tail pointer..